# "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to get lat, lng from a KML-layer to Google Maps [Xamarin Android]

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently working with a KML-file via this plugin: https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover.Android.Maps.Utils

The KML-file i am using gets added succesfully via this codesnippet:

```
var kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, Resource.Raw.campus, Android.App.Application.Context);
kmlLayer.AddLayerToMap();
MoveCameraToKml(kmlLayer);
```

When it's added I run my `MoveCameraToKml`function where I try to get the lat, lng of every point but I get a crash on this row `foreach (LatLng latLng in ((KmlLineString)geo).GeometryObject);` with the errormessage: `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

```
void MoveCameraToKml(KmlLayer kmlLayer)
{
  //Retrieve the first container in the KML layer
  var container = (KmlContainer)kmlLayer.Containers.Iterator().Next();

  //Retrieve a nested container within the first container
  container = (KmlContainer)container.Containers.Iterator().Next();

  //Retrieve the first placemark in the nested container
  var placemark = (KmlPlacemark)container.Placemarks.Iterator().Next();
  var geo = placemark.Geometry;
  if (geo is KmlLineString)
  {
      foreach (LatLng latLng in ((KmlLineString)geo).GeometryObject) //object reference not set to an instance of an object
      {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(latLng); 
      }
   }

}
```

Any idea why this is giving me a crash? I am following the example of the nuget I downloaded above.

The idea is to store the lat, lngs in a list and use a `PolylineOptions` to create routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Google sample (`MoveCameraToKml`) assumes that you are using their Campus KML example. Since the KML you use will be unique to your app, you will need to review your KML/XML elements and write your code to suit your usage.

Here is an example using their Grand Canyon KML `LineString` hiking path:

- https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#paths

So looking at the KML, we will need to:

1. Get the first `Container`
2. Get the first `Placemark` in that container
3. Check if it has geometry and is a KML `LineString`
4. Obtain the `LatLng` array via `GeometryJavaObject()`
5. Use those Latlngs to build a camera viewport and move to it.
6. "Drive" the camera along those individual points

#### Grand Canyon KmlLineString Example:

```
void MoveCameraToKml(KmlLayer kmlLayer)
{
    var container = (KmlContainer)kmlLayer.Containers.Iterator().Next();
    var placemark = (KmlPlacemark)container.Placemarks.Iterator().Next();
    if (placemark.HasGeometry && placemark.Geometry is KmlLineString)
    {
        var lineString = placemark.Geometry as KmlLineString;
        var latlngArray = lineString.GeometryJavaObject() as Java.Util.ArrayList;
        using (var builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder())
        {
            foreach (LatLng latLng in latlngArray.ToEnumerable())
            {
                builder.Include(latLng);
            }
            googleMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(
                builder.Build(), mapFragment.View.Width, mapFragment.View.Height, 1)
            );
        }
        Task.Run(async () => // run camera along KmlLineString
        {
            foreach (LatLng latLng in latlngArray.ToEnumerable())
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                RunOnUiThread(() => googleMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLng(latLng)));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! I get out the coordinates now and I build it with a polyline. Now I have one last thing left which is to remove the pins that I get when I add a the kmllayer. Should be interesting :)

Comment: I fixed that problem by just removing the layer afterwards `RemoveLayerFromMap` because i already got out the coordinates that i needed. I notice though that the code only makes one route when there are supposed to be two routes in that KML-file. Maybe the KML-file is setup the wrong way. I will need to look at that.

Answer (score 0):

[Geometry](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/kml/KmlPlacemark.html) can be KmlPoint, KmlLineString, KmlPolygon or a KmlMultiGeometry.

```
var geo = placemark.Geometry;
if (geo is KmlPolygon) then {
  var poly = (KmlPolygon)geo;
}
```

Comment: I tried replacing `KmlPolygin` with `KmlLineString` and looped it like this `foreach (LatLng latLng in polygon.GeometryObject)` but that gave me `object reference not set to an instance of an object` I am working the with KmlPoint now but I am unsure how to loop out all of the points with that one.

Comment: you can't cast it unless you know which type it is.  You need to check the type before casting.

Comment: ok i make some progress, i updated the code with ur example and it is a "KmlLineString" I am working with apparently. When I try to get out the lat,lng i get a `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: If i do this: `var locations = ((KmlLineString)geo).GeometryObject;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(locations.Count());`Error: value cannot be null

Comment: you really need to use the debugger to examine the data you're working with instead of making assumptions about what it looks like